# NextJs export folder "out" doesn't have index.html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, deployment

I’ve built a Next.js app, and I wanted to use static exporting to host the project on my hosting. The app is simple, so I didn’t use most of the features that Next.js offers. When I run:
`npm run build (next build && next export)` 
i get .next folder and out folder which has the following folders:
`/static /chunks /css /media`

I have all the needed settings (ie:  output: "export", in next.config.js..)

I'm supposed to get all the static HTML files..but i haven’t get those, any solutions please?

---

Update:

This happened because image optimization is active and works under the hood,for that the app has to run on a server but i'm trying to generate a static website, i disabled it by adding the following to next.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    unoptimized: true,
  },
}
```

And it worked as expected.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Celsiuss The question is pretty clear, I have the exact same issue of NextJs not generating any html files after the static export.

Comment: @khaled after disabling the image-optimization, it also generated the correct html files for me, although I still need some sort of http server, because the html files use leading `/` in all urls and `file://` protocol doesn't handle that properly.

Comment: As mentioned in the Update section, images.unoptimized = true fixed this issue.

Answer (score -1):

The output of `next export` doesn't necessarily include an `index.html` file.

There will be one HTML file for each file inside the `/pages` folder.

E.g. if you have a file `/pages/start.js`, then there will be a file inside the output folder: `/out/start.html`.

Only if you have a file `/pages/index.js`, then there will also be a `/out/index.html` file.

Comment: I have `/pages/index.js` and `/pages/posts/first-post.js`, but still I don't have any html file in the the `out` folder.